# python 3.8 , Problem installing matplotlib . Visual Studio 2010 build tools not found

Tags: python, matplotlib

when trying to install matplotlib via pip i get this

> "FreeType version 2.3 or higher is required. You may set the
>   MPLLOCALFREETYPE environment variable to 1 to let Matplotlib download
>   it."

so i use command

```
set MPLLOCALFREETYPE=1
```

and try again and get this instead

> error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform
>   Toolset = 'v100') cann ot be found. To build using the v100 build
>   tools, please install Visual Studio 2010 build tools.  Alternatively,
>   you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the
>   Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget
>   solution".
>   [C:\Users\digikwondo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3ci6qqh3\matplotlib\build\freetype-2.6.1\builds\windows\vc2010\freetype.vcxproj]
>       Done Building Project "C:\Users\digikwondo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3ci6qqh3\matplotlib\build\freetype-2.6.1\builds\windows\vc2010\freetype.vcxproj"
>   (default targets) -- FAILED.
>       Done Building Project "C:\Users\digikwondo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3ci6qqh3\matplotlib\build\freetype-2.6.1\builds\windows\vc2010\freetype.sln"
>   (Clean;Build target(s)) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.

i am building on windows 10 and have the following visual studio build tools packages installed

- Windows Universal C Runtime
- C++ Build Tools core features
- MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.24)
- C++ CMake tools for Windows
- .NET Framework 4.8 SDK
- .NET Framework 4.6.1 targeting pack
- C++/CLI support for v142 build tools (14.24)
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17134.0)
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299.0)
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0)
- C++ core features
- Windows Universal CRT SDK
- NuGet targets and build tasks
- .NET Framework 4.6 targeting pack
- C++ Universal Windows Platform runtime for v142 build tools
- Visual Studio SDK Build Tools Core
- C++ Windows XP Support for VS 2017 (v141) tools
- MSVC v141 - VS 2017 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.16)
- MSVC v140 - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00)
- C++/CLI support for v142 build tools (14.24)
- C++ Modules for v142 build tools (x64/x86 – experimental)
- MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.24)
- C++ CMake tools for Windows
- Testing tools core features - Build Tools
- C++ AddressSanitizer (Experimental)

i have a feeling there is something simple i am missing here. would appreciate any guidance
as im quite stuck.  (installing with python 3.7 in separate venv instead of python 3.8 works ok on same win 10 machine. )